# Change the 'save as' type to .xls dialog box in IE (Internet Explorer) using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a problem when Convert table from HTML to Excel file using JQuery in Internet Explorer, the dialog box that appear shows the file type as HTML;I want to change the file type to .xls ,how can I solve that?

and that's my code:

```
 $("#btnExport").click(function () {
            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
            var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

            if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
            {
                txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
                txtArea1.document.write($('#divExport').html());
                txtArea1.document.close();
                txtArea1.focus();
                sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "FileName.xls");
            }
            return false;
        });
```

as that:
[image: Save as]

Comment: You do know that this method is IE-only, right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes sure I know that

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.

[A security warning](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/743974/) about using this method in the first place states:

> The "Save as type" field of the dialog always displays "HTML File (*.htm; *.html)," regardless of the content that it is actually saving.

It would really be best to avoid this non-standard feature. It's not fit for purpose.